# ubuntu can't detect wifi mac

Tags: wireless, drivers, mac

I have installed ubuntu(12.04.1 LTS) on my mac air 6.1, but it can't detect any wifi.
I was told that I should install a network card driver.

but I have tried to search on google but i got nothing.
because I type:  lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
to detect the device and I got this:
Network controller[0280]:broadcom corporation device 14e4:43a0
I saw lots of things about broadcom bcm**** but I think mine is different from the bcm****.

can u help me?
what should i do?
thx in advance.

Comment: The exact solution depends on your Ubuntu version. We hope it is 13.10. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsb_release -d

Comment: I got this: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

A later bcmwl-kernel-source package (i.e. bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3) does have support for the chipset Broadcom BCM4360, PCI-ID 14e4:43a0. The catch is that this package was part of the Saucy release (i.e. Ubuntu 13.10) so for now it needs to be installed manually in Precise (i.e. Ubuntu 12.04). To determine which version you need, find out if you have a 32- or 64-bit installation:

```
arch
```

If your is 32-bit (i686), you need to dowbload this to your desktop: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/143917601/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb

If 64-bit (x86_64), then this: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/143917424/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

Both packages require dependencies. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms libc6-dev linux-libc-dev
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and give us your report.

Comment: thx a lot! i ll try